# AWS Aurora: What is 'delayed send/commit ok done' process state

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

What do the following process states mean in AWS Aurora (MYSQL-Compatible)

- `delayed send ok done`
- `delayed commit ok done`

Noticing many sleeping processes with the above state. These seem to Aurora-specific.

Are these states any indicators of underlying performance issues with my queries or Tables?

Comment: One possible reason could be due to transactions. Refer https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=771651&tstart=0

Comment: I would really like an answer on this as well. The forum post in the previous comment is more focused on the "Cleaned Up" state and doesn't acknowledge the "Delayed Send/Commit OK Done" state specifically.

Comment: This was answered by Amazon staff:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=708499
-
"In Aurora the 'cleaned up' state is the final state of a connection whose work is complete but which has not been closed from the client side. In MySQL this field is left blank (no State) in the same circumstance."